# How to remove written out date strings like "1. January" from a list?

Tags: python, string, date

I have a list that looks like this: `["Keyphrase", "27. August", "8. April"]`

I have tried out this code, but havent found the right regex to remove number plus month strings from the list.

```
new_list = [x for x in old_list if not re.search(r'<insert regex>', x)]
```

I would like to remove all "number + month" items to have the final list look like this: ["Keyphrase"]

Comment: Post your regex.

Comment: is the order random or could you not just take the first element in the list?

Comment: Post the expected result.

Comment: Instead of using regex, maybe you can consider splitting the text by ‘.’ , get the last in list, remove the first char (which is a space), and check is it a month name?

Comment: I also want to keep the case: ["Keyphrase", "27. August", "8. April", "2. Senat"] -> ["Keyphrase", "2. Senat"]

Comment: Worked?...have u tested?

Answer (score 1):

single line no regex - use a list comp and any instead:

```
l=  ["Keyphrase", "27. August", "8. April"]

months= ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']


print ([el for el in l if not any(ignore in el for ignore in months)])
```

output #

```
['Keyphrase']
```

**Example i/p2**

```
l=["Keyphrase", "27. August", "8. April", "2. Senat"]
```

output 2#

```
['Keyphrase', '2. Senat']
```